# What kinds of table talk are allowed in Shadows Over Camelot?

Tags: shadows-over-camelot

Games like Battle Star Galactica define pretty clearly what kind of table talk is allowed during the game to help give the Cylon Traitor a chance to remain hidden.

What, if any table talk is allowed in Shadows Over Camelot?
What kind of talk is specifically forbidden?

Can you for example peek at the Progression of Evil deck (with the appropriate knight), and then say "don't draw from the deck," or "the top card is everyone lose a life," or can you say nothing?

Similarly, with King Arthur, you pass cards face down. I assume you cannot reveal what each player passed the other after the fact (hands should remain hidden, right)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 8, of the [Official Rules](http://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/shadowsovercamelot/en/img/sc_rules_en.pdf) talks about collaboration.

1. You can talk about, generally, what you're going to do.
2. You can talk about, generally, what your hand can do in terms of your previous intent
3. You can not talk about specific cards.

After a peek, you can say "This would be bad, take a catapult instead",  but you cannot say "This causes everyone to lose a life" as it will identify that specific card.

Similarly, you can't ask for a "Fight 5" or use any kind of code that will 'get across' the hint of what card you need (e.g. "I need a very powerful warrior, sir" is cheating).

Hands remain hidden, all specifics are hidden.

The best and more fun way I've found to enforce these rules is to speak only 'in character' in the game.  "Sir Arthur, my men-at-arms are lacking in strength to seek the armor, please assist".   Or, "I have heard rumors of the location of the grail, shall I go seek it, or does someone else feel that can find it before me?"